# Links overflowing out of container div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jQuery animation for my banner area on my webpage which is run on the body load. The banner display is set to none initially, which is then changed when the function runs.

```
function displayExpand()
    {
    $('#displayArea').slideDown('slow', function(){});
    }
```

For some strange reason the container for the navigation menu overflows and each link stacks on top of itself on the far right side of the page.
 What is even stranger is that this ONLY happens when I refresh the page. If I access the page from another link the navigation menu will look fine. It also only seems to happen when I run it in chrome

CSS

```
#linkContainer {
    margin-top:20px;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    height:55px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="linkContainer">
    <div class="mybuttons" style="color:#C00; font-weight:bold;">Home</div>
    <a href="about.html" style="text-decoration:none"><div class="mybuttons">About</div></a>
    <a href="portfolio.html" style="text-decoration:none"><div class="mybuttons">Portfolio</div></a>
    <a href="resume.html" style="text-decoration:none"><div class="mybuttons">Resume</div></a>
    <a href="contact.html" style="text-decoration:none"><div class="mybuttons">Contact</div></a>
</div>
```

Any suggestions why?

Comment: Do you want to display the links like `HOME     ABOUT US         Portfolio     Resume     Contact`.....?

Comment: I mean you want like navigationbar..??

Comment: Yes, in a horizontal order on the far right side of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display them in a horizontal nav bar. Then instead of `div's` use `<li>`

**Here is the code:**

**HTML**

```
<div id="linkContainer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <ul>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#linkContainer {
margin-top:20px;
float:right;
height:55px;
width:auto;
}

ul li
{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-table;
    padding-left:30px;
}
```

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 1):

```
.mybuttons {
    margin-top:20px;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    height:55px;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 1px
}

#linkContainer {
    margin-top:20px;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    height:55px;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 1px
}
```

try to apply it on div with the class `.mybutton` 
http://jsfiddle.net/j6UhE/3/

Comment: I want the links to be on the far right side though, as I use an image on the left side.

Comment: @user2330621 try to apply css to .mybutons class check out here http://jsfiddle.net/j6UhE/3/

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTMl to

```
<ul id="linkContainer">
<li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="resume.html" >Resume</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and CSS as

```
ul#linkContainer{ float:right}
ul#linkContainer li{ float:left:margin-right:5px;}
ul#linkContainer li a.active{color:#C00; font-weight:bold;}
ul#linkContainer li a{ display:block;text-decoration:none}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to get rig of `divs` in `anchors`: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yDm7/)